# Elementary cannot see phone while there is no internet connection

Tags: usb-drive, android

I got a strange problem, because when I want plug my phone (Android 5.1) to my laptop with Elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya everything is works, but when I disconnect from internet and try to plug my device Elementary cannot show me my files on phone (Unable to Mount Folder).

Thanks for help.